# C# interop to XPCOM

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling, xpcom, geckofx

Before asking my question, I should admit that my knowledge of .NET interop is sparse, so I realize that I might be making a newbie error.

I am using the [GeckoFx](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) library to create a C# application that contains an embedded Gecko (Firefox) browser instance. The app works well using GeckoFx in its original form, but I need to extend it to support XPath queries, using the Mozilla `nsIDOMXPathEvaluator` interface.

The GeckoFx codebase includes numerous examples of exposing and using the underlying managed Gecko interfaces, and I have followed the same code patterns to expose several new interfaces:

```
[Guid("75506f8a-b504-11d5-a7f2-ca108ab8b6fc"),
    ComImport,
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface nsIDOMXPathEvaluator
{
    nsIDOMXPathExpression CreateExpression(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string expression,
        nsIDOMXPathNSResolver resolver);

    nsIDOMXPathNSResolver CreateNSResolver(
        nsIDOMNode nodeResolver);

    nsISupports Evaluate(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string expression,
        nsIDOMNode contextNode,
        nsIDOMXPathNSResolver resolver,
        ushort type);
}

[Guid("ce600ca8-e98a-4419-ad61-2f6d0cb0ecc8"),
    ComImport,
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface nsIDOMXPathExpression
{
    nsISupports Evaluate(
        nsIDOMNode contextNode,
        ushort type,
        nsISupports result);
}

[Guid("75506f83-b504-11d5-a7f2-ca108ab8b6fc"),
    ComImport,
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface nsIDOMXPathNSResolver
{
    string LookupNamespaceUri(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string prefix);
}
```

With the new interfaces exposed, I attempt to use `nsIDOMXPathEvaluator` to evaluate an XPath expression in the context of the loaded DOM:

```
var evaluator = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsIDOMXPathEvaluator>("@mozilla.org/dom/xpath-evaluator;1");
var node = (nsIDOMNode)Document.DocumentElement.DomObject;
var resolver = evaluator.CreateNSResolver(node);
var result = evaluator.Evaluate("//div[0]", node, resolver, 0);
```

Although the first three variables are correctly populated, the call to `Evaluate` fails with an exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory.". I am inclined to believe that the problem lies in the way my code marshals string values, as I have seen different exception messages when experimenting with the marshalled type of the expression parameter.

It seems that I am not the only person suffering this problem, as shown in [this forum post](http://geckofx.org/viewtopic.php?id=809), but I cannot understand how my implementation differs from the many other working examples in the GeckoFx library.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here.

1) You're missing an argument in the nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.Evaluate method. You need an nsISupports argument that can be used to collect the result (actually an nsIDOMXPathResult ) if you do not want to create a new nsIDOMXPathResult object.

2) These interfaces don't use normal strings that you can marshal that way. If you look at the document page for [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMXPathEvaluator) for instance, you will see that evaluate takes a DOMString rather than string or wstring. In GeckoFx you can use nsAString for DOMString.

So nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.Evaluate will look like this:

```
nsISupports Evaluate(
    nsAString expression,
    nsIDOMNode contextNode,
    nsIDOMXPathNSResolver resolver,
    ushort type, nsISupports result );
```

And nsIDOMXPathNSResolver.LookupNamespaceUri will look like this:

```
nsAString LookupNamespaceUri( nsAString prefix );
```

Now you should be able to do this:

```
var evaluator = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsIDOMXPathEvaluator>("@mozilla.org/dom/xpath-evaluator;1");
var node = (nsIDOMNode)Document.DocumentElement.DomObject;
var resolver = evaluator.CreateNSResolver(node);
var result = evaluator.Evaluate(new nsAString(@"//div[0]"), node, resolver, 0, null);
```

And now you should not experience any exceptions, and result should be valid. But what you do with result will be another matter. You'll need to implement a few other interfaces to make much use of it, but that should get you on the right path.

Cheers

Comment: thank you so much - your answer is exactly right. I corrected the two errors in my code and added the interface definition for nsIDOMXPathResult and now I am able to retrieve a node result and use it to initialize a new GeckoNode instance. Thanks again.